# Properties of $\mathcal{o}$ notation

Tags: asymptotics

I have some trouble understanding how $\mathcal{o}$-notation works.
Take for example $f \in \mathcal{o}(n^{-1/2})$. Then what would the limiting behavior of $nf$ or $f^2$ be?

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! Is $n$ tending to $\infty$ or to $0$ ?

Comment: $f$ must satisfy $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(n)\cdot \sqrt{n}=0$$ Hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f^2(n)\cdot n=0$$ so we have $f^2\in o(n^{-1})$.

Comment: Not sure, but I think the behaviour of $nf$ depends on $f$

Comment: I think by multiplying and dividing by $n$, one has $$\lim_n \frac{n f(n)}{\frac{n}{\sqrt{n}}} = \lim_n \frac{n f(n)}{\sqrt{n}} = 0$$ So $n f \in \operatorname{o}(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @AlexVong $n^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 0):

We have, if $f\in \mathcal{o}(a(n))$ and $g\in \mathcal{O}(b(n))$,  then $f g\in \mathcal{o}(a(n)b(n))$. Also, $\mathcal{o}(a(n)) \subset \mathcal{O}(a(n))$. These two facts will give you the limiting behaviors you want to find. Note $n\in \mathcal{O}(n)$.